# Drawback of mixing C++ code with C for performance purposes

Tags: c++, c

Often you can see answers like “Avoid using C libraries in your C++ code“ or “This can be rewritten using STD/Boost in pure C++“.

I understand C++ produces more maintainable code and has many advantages, but is it actually bad using C libraries when performance is a priority? I mean writing in what is sometimes  called C-with-classes.

I‘ve been developing a text file parser with both C and C++ versions and the C one was considerably faster.

What i would like to know is if using C libraries in C++ has hidden drawbacks apart from the obvious ones like making the code less maintainable.

Comment: "the C one was considerably faster" - if you would post an example from that lib (and the C++ alternative you have used), I guess the community here could tell you here the necessary improvements in your C++ code to make the speed difference neglectable.

Comment: You can use one of the approaches listed in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11006796/377657 (either using a profiler tool that *understands the C++ string templates*, or write your own performance tracer.)

Comment: A classic read: [Raymond Chen v. Rico Mariani, with commentaries by Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/05/on-managed-code-performance-again.html)

Comment: @Doc Brown Unfortunately i don‘t have a C++ version anymore since i kept the C one without the care of making a backup of both. The difference in performance was on file reading (streams in C++ vere much slower, i think because of buffering) and string tokenization (strtok vs stringstream). I know there had must been a way to make the C++ code almost as fast as the C one, but I don't think that was worth the effort.

Comment: @rwong: the link is interesting, but I think one should add that the situation in C vs. C++ is IMHO not always comparable to "C++ vs. C#".

Comment: @user39517: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289347/using-strtok-with-a-stdstring for the strtok vs. stringstream issue. Seeing the different answers, I can perfectly understand why one would prefer the "strtok" solution (which is simple and fast), but as you see, one can use it together with std::string, or use the Boost alternative which I guess won't be really slower.

Comment: @user39517: and here a a link about the file streams issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425414/using-ofstream-for-buffered-output-to-gain-performance , maybe this helps.

Answer (score 8):

> is it actually bad using C libraries when performance is a priority?

It is if you don't actually need the performance boost that the C library would provide, or the C library only produces a minimal performance increase, because you're trading off too many of the benefits you get by using STD/Boost.

If:

1. You profile your code using STD/Boost, and
2. You profile your code using C libraries, and
3. There is a significant performance improvement with the C libraries, and
4. You actually *need* the performance improvement; i.e. using the C libraries fixes an actual performance *problem*

Then I would say that the C library is a better choice.  But about 99 percent of the time, it won't be the best choice, because the performance increase (if there is one) will be so small that it won't be worth it.

**Further Reading**
[Using/Mixing C in C++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4025869) on StackOverflow

Comment: Would you be willing to share a bit about situations where C might legitimately be faster? I know arguments about things like dynamic dispatch, etc. maybe make sense here but if you know more, I think it would improve the answer. I'd love to find out if you've ever run into any scenarios where the C library made sense for you to use instead.

Comment: @JTrana: there is only one ultima ratio for C beeing *significantly* faster than C++ - measurement (as Robert wrote in his answer).

Answer (score 4):

C++ programmers seem to have a fear of not using enough of the language's features all the time. 'C with classes' can be a perfectly acceptable solution if it solves your problem, and writing libraries in C gives you the advantage of being able to use them with other languages too.

You will have to ensure any resources allocated by you library have explicit ownership or you'll get leaks.

Having said this I'm surprised your C code outperformed your C++ code, this indicates an issue with your C++ code (you're probably using std::string all over the place)

Comment: +1 for "this indicates an issue with your C++ code", that is actually what I thought, too, when I read the question.